# Цикл foreach в переменной

Tags: php, foreach

Как можно записать следующий код по-другому?

```
$errors .=

    "<li>Его ключ =" .

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$key];
    } . 

    "его наличие = {$_SESSION['auth'][$id]['nalichies']}</li>";
```

Сейчас выходит ошибка `syntax error unexpected t-foreach`.

Возможно надо записать по-другому?

```
[cart] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 2
                [name] => Название 1
                [price] => 999
                [img] => 1.jpg
                [nalichies] => 2
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 3
                [name] => Название 2
                [price] => 750
                [img] => no_image.jpg
                [nalichies] => 53
            )

    )
```

Вот сам код выполнения:

```
$errors = ''; // флаг проверки пустых полей   
$name = trim($_POST['name_zakaz']);

if(empty($name)) $errors .= '<li>Не указано <strong>ФИО</strong></li>';

//ТАК РАБОТАЕТ (то, что нужно). Но, если реализовать на данных основанных из корзины - так не правильно, т.к. $vnal можно подделать.  Поэтому хочется брать данные из сессии корзины, как показано на 2-ом for
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_POST['na']);$i++ ) {
    $id = $_POST["na"][$i]; // уникальный id товара
    $vnal = $_POST["nas"][$i]; // имеющееся количество товара
    $kolvo = $_POST["nass"][$i]; // количество введенное заказчиком
    if ($kolvo > $vnal) { //если заказчик ввел кол-во товаров больше числа доступных товаров
        $errors .= "<li>Товара с id = {$id} в кол-ве {$kolvo} шт. нет в наличии!</li>";
    }            
} 
//ТАК НЕ РАБОТАЕТ.
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_POST['na']);$i++ ) {
    $id = $_POST["na"][$i]; // уникальный id товара - его, конечно, надо тоже брать из сессии корзины
    $kolvo_tovara_v_korzine = $_POST["nass"][$i]; // количество введенное заказчиком уже брать методом POST

    if ($kolvo_tovara_v_korzine > $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['nalichies']) { //если заказчик ввел кол-во товара больше числа имеющегося наличия                      
        $errors .= "<li>Товар с id =" .(foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value){$_SESSION['cart'][$key];}). "не может содержаться в количестве: {$kolvo_tovara_v_korzine} шт.</li>";                       
    }    //Также хотелось бы                           
} 

if(empty($errors)){
    // выполнение кода           
}else{
// если не заполнены обязательные поля и другие возможные ошибки
    $_SESSION['order']['res'] = "<div class='errorREG'><strong>Ошибка оформления заказа:</strong> <ul class='ulError'>{$errors}</ul></div>";
    $_SESSION['order']['name'] = $name;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `implode(', ',$_SESSION['cart'])`

Comment: @vp_arth не, так не выйдет. Ни чего не выведет на экран. `$_SESSION['cart']` это массив и в нём содержится ключ с массивом, а возможно и несколько ключей.

Comment: Ок, я попытался..

Comment: @vp_arth Спасибо!

Comment: Покажите $session.

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Что вы ожидаете увидеть на выходе. Примерно

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin Вообщем ситуация такая. Я хочу сделать проверку при оформлении заказа. Если клиент вводит кол-во товара больше, чем есть в наличии, выводить ему сообщение об этом, причем он может не только у одного товара превысить кол-во, но и 2-х и более. Поэтому хочется показать на экране, что такой-то товар(ы) нельзя добавить в таком кол-ве. Переменная $errors .=  дописывается к другим возможным ошибкам (не заполнил поле телефон). Т.е. в ошибке мне надо показать в каком товаре превышено кол-во.

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin Там даже for приходится использовать, т.к. товаров много может быть и кол-во введенное соответственно надо брать всех. Могу показать код весь, если необходимо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте формировать $_POST['nass'] так:

```
<imput type="number" name="nass[<?=product_id;?>]" value="{customer_entered_qty}" />
```

Достаньте из $_post nass:

```
$post_nass = $_POST['nass'];
```

И добавлять сверку session_qty и customer_entered_qty:

```
foreach($session as $sess_k => $sess_v){

    foreach($post_nass as $post_k => $post_v){

       $post_v = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string(abs((int)$post_v))));

       if($post_k == $sess_v['name'] && $post_v > $sess_k['nalichies']){
           $errors .= "<li>нельзя купить " . $sess_k['qty'] . "ед. " . $sess_k['name'] . " - в наличии: " . $sess_k['nalichies'] . "</li>";
       }

    }

}
```

Для идентификации единицы товара лучше всё же использовать id а не name.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53899/discussion-on-answer-by-kirill-korushkin--foreach--).

Answer (score 1):

Было бы круто показать в каком виде хранится информация в глобальном массиве `$_SESSION['cart']` и что вы ожидаете увидеть на выходе.

*Насколько я понял, вы имели ввиду это...*

```
$errors .= "<li>Его ключ =";
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
    $errors .= $value; // Если нужен только ключ, то вместо $value подставьте $key
}
$errors .= "его наличие = {$_SESSION['auth'][$id]['nalichies']}</li>";
```